# Qualified names for JSON objects

Tags: java, json

Since the json objects are limited in usage of characters I'm looking for a better description for this. The json file will be used later as a table and therefore the objects are the head and the values are the content of the table.

```
   {
  "employees": {
    "employee": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Cruise"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Sharapova"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Bond"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Therefore I'm looking to use something like a header where I can define the names. These names shall replace the object strings.

e.g.

```
    {
"header": {
"id":"Identifikation",
"firstName":"First Name",
"lastName":"Last Name"
}
}
```

How can use such name convention replacement? Do json provide such 'heading' object?

Comment: No, JSON is just a textual data bag with arbitrary data. You can supply such a "heading" meta object into the JSON yourself and process it in any way you want, or transfer such a mapping as another document. If you cannot control the JSON documents you're going to process, the mapping should be stored elsewhere.

Comment: If you provided the JSON library you are using and the code in question someone might be able to offer some suggestions of how to accomplish what you want.